# Compiling VB Code With CodeDom

Tags: vb.net, codedom

Read up on it, couldn't find anything that worked for me.
Basically, I have a file called SourceCode.vb in my resources.
I'm trying to use:

```
Dim objCodeCompiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler = New VBCodeProvider().CreateCompiler
Dim objCompilerParameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Deployment.dll")
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
objCompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = True
objCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = False
objCompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
objCompilerParameters.OutputAssembly = "C:\"
Dim strCode As String = My.Resources.SourceCode.ToString
Dim objCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, strCode)
If objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors Then
    MsgBox("Error: Line>" & objCompileResults.Errors(0).Line.ToString & ", " & objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I need it to compile the code and make the file and place it in C:\ - For some reason its not working. Error is:

> error: line>0, no input sources specified

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Problem was that I needed to add an actual name for the file after the output. Thanks for the help Hans.

Comment: Are you sure your source code is actually contained in strCode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0kc0z48(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Im 100% sure, just checked.

Comment: Well, that's not a fantastic error message.  It is *actually* complaining about your OutputAssembly assignment.  You have to specify a file name, not a directory name.  Like "c:\test.exe".  Which you should not use either, you cannot write to the root directory of the c: drive.  Better if you omit it completely, you'll get an assembly in the TEMP directory.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually because you are setting OutputAssembly to a location when it expects an assembly name. It should be:

```
objCompilerParameters.OutputAssembly = "AssemblyName.exe"
```

If you want to set the location of the output assembly, add it to your compiler options.

```
objCompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe /out:C:\\AssemblyName.exe"
```

Although, I believe if you want to write to the C: drive, you will need to run your program as administrator.